# How to make laravel validator for all input files in form

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I try to add validator for all input type file in my form. I do not use input type file "multiple."
When page is loaded, my form has only one input file. Then user can add other files by clicking on "add" button.
So I need to make validation rules for all inputs type file added dynamically.
Maybe the question seems stupid, but I don't want input multiple, the boss finds it "not user friendly".
How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple input field as dynamic, like :

```
<input name="image[]" type="file">
<input name="image[]" type="file">
```

On your controller you will receive it as an **array**, so you can validate like :

```
$data = $request->validate([
    "image"    => "required|array",  // array validation
    "image.*"  => "required|image|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,jpg", // field validation from the array
]);
```

Comment: I am using input type file. Do you try to tell me to apply same solution?

Comment: @Cutis you can validate anything you want. I updated the answer  for image validation

Answer (score 0):

Just set the a single name for each input file that is added and add `[]` to the end of the name

```
<input name="file_input[]" type="file">
<input name="file_input[]" type="file">
<input name="file_input[]" type="file">
<input name="file_input[]" type="file">
```

The in your controller method first validate it as an array
then validate the contents

if you want atleast one file add `min:1` to the validator options

```
$data = $request->validate([
    "file_input"    => "required|array|min:1",  // array validation atleast one file is needed
    "file_input.*"  => "required|file|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,jpg,pdf,doc", // field validation from the array
]);
```

else

```
$data = $request->validate([
    "file_input"    => "required|array",  // array validation
    "file_input.*"  => "required|file|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,jpg,pdf,doc", // field validation from the array
]);
```